# MAUI EventToCommandBehavior

Tags: mvvm, maui, eventtocommand

XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
        EventName="OnAppearing"
        Command="{Binding AppearingExeCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public void AppearingExe()
{
    try
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Reset();
        if (!WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.IsRegistered<MyMessage>(this))
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, OnMessageReceived);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception er)
    {
        Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", er.Message, "OK");
    }
}
```

Running an error:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

What is the reason? How should I handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `OnAppearing` event on ContentPage, only a method with that name. You need to use the `Appearing` [event of ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.contentpage#events):

```xml
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
        EventName="Appearing"
        Command="{Binding AppearingExeCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Sure enough, thank you very much!

Comment: @LiJerry Did this fix it?

Comment: Yes, the problem has been resolved. Thank you again!